Coercing columns of partitions to common supertype on `pl.scan_parquet`
I have a parquet table where some columns have varying datatype precision across partitions (e.g. float32 & float64).
Is there a way to coerce these to a compatible supertype?
I am looking for the same behavior that would take place if I were to pl.concat(individually_scanned_partitions, how="vertical_relaxed")
The error I am getting when trying to load a table with differing dtypes is
SchemaError: dtypes differ for column XXX: Float64 != Float32

What tool did you use to write such cursed data?

@orlp Can you not guess? :P Pandas

How many columns are we talking about? Could you implement a manual cast that is performed before concatenation?

@Hericks that is my current solution, I scan each partition individually and then do the concatenation with "vertical_relaxed" but the performance is unusable.
I understand my usecase probably isn't the most common so I am okay with doing this for the couple of tables I am loading, but was wondering if there's some better solution.
